printerJob.printDialog() permanently blocking
Im trying to create a simple method to print an image but whenever i call job.printDialog() it 1: never returns a value, and 2: permanently blocks my window being used by the rest of the program. I am running on Mac IOS

    private void printImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        Printable printImage = new Printable() {
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
                if (pageIndex > 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
                g2d.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        };
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(printImage);
        
        if (job.printDialog()) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                job.cancel();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

                                                        .

